# NameError: name 'process_or_store' is not defined, python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I tried to execute this code and I get this error message :

> NameError: name 'process_or_store' is not defined,

I tried all related solutions here and nothing worked. How can I get rid of the error message?

```
import tweepy
import json
import nltk

from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener



consumer_key = 'key'
consumer_secret = 'secret'
access_token = '-token'
access_secret = 'secret'

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items(10):
    # Process a single status
     process_or_store(status.json)
```

Comment: where do you define your `process_or_store` method?

Comment: so how can i solve it?

Comment: ...define it? Where did you think `process_or_store` would come from, exactly?

Comment: Duplicate of - http://marcobonzanini.com/2015/03/02/mining-twitter-data-with-python-part-1/comment-page-1/#comment-258 - where this code is from originally.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by R Nar, the `process_or_store` method has not been defined. You can read more about how to do that [here](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html).

[As explained by the author](http://marcobonzanini.com/2015/03/02/mining-twitter-data-with-python-part-1/comment-page-1/#comment-258):

> The function `process_or_store()` is a place-holder for your custom implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for -

```
    def process_or_store(tweet):
        print(json.dumps(tweet))
```

Don't forget to import simplejson as json before using this block of code. And this was available on the website which you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:
print(json.dumps(friend._json))

in place of

process_or_store(friend._json)